# How to check what/why stopped Tomcat?

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have Tomcat 6 on Debian 5 on VPS. Sometimes Tomcat stop responses, and when I then checked server there is no Tomcat process and none exception to this in Tomcat logs.

How can I check what killed Tomcat process?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to search in syslog: /var/log/*

for the messages (syslog) use the following command:

```
tail /var/log/syslog
```

and you will get the last 5 or so log messages.

here's an article on debians syslog: http://www.aboutdebian.com/syslog.htm

Oli

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in /var/log/syslog. Probably your tomcat eat a lot of memory and the oom-killer is taking action: http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer

Regards

Comment: Tomcat has ~ 970M and is still 2GB free on server.

Comment: Look on /var/log/syslog and see if something with oom appear there.

Comment: nothing with oom, tomcat or java in syslog

Answer (score -1):

There's an article http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html about the logging in tomcat. I haven't tried it but it looks promising.

Oli